# Refused visa from USA. Letter is lost, so what can I disclose for New Zealand visa?

Tags: visas, usa, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, new-zealand

I applied for a USA visitor visa back in 2018 but was refused. I lost the refusal letter but didn't read it thoroughly and now I don't remember the reason of the refusal.

Now I am planning for a vacation in New Zealand for 7 days in winter 2022, and Question F4 of the New Zealand Visitor Visa application reads:

> "Have you, or has anyone included in this application, ever been
> refused a visa/permit to visit, work, study or reside in any country?
> [] Yes [] No

And then:

> If you have answered yes to any of the questions above give full
> details. This includes full details of any charges, convictions and
> the sentence or penalty imposed. Continue on a separate piece of paper
> if necessary."

What should I do or what can I disclose in response to the question above? I don't want to get into trouble and possibly be banned on deception. I will gladly inquire to the US embassy if they can provide me another copy of the letter I lost.

Comment: NZ might be different but for an Australian working visa I just wrote down the country, visa type, and year I was refused a visa.

Comment: The rejection letter from the US has always been distressingly generic, citing a very broad section of laws that really give no insight into the actual reason for rejection; to get the details you had to have asked the interviewing officer.

Comment: I have never applied for a NZ visa but I expect that if you do not lie there will be no deception refusal (but idk if they will refuse you for other reasons). If I was applying for any visa and I could not remember the answer to a question and could not find out, I would say so. However, you might consider whether the USA could tell you the reason you were refused.